# QTimer doesn't call timeout slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qthread, qtimer

I was trying to use a `QTimer` within different `QThread`, but I couldn't connect to the `QTimer`'s `timeout()` slot.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
extern MainWindow *mainClass;

class myObj : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myObj(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~myObj();
    QThread workerThread;

    int percent;
    QTimer *percentTimer;

public slots:
    void doWork();
    void percentUpdate();
    void startFunction();

signals:
    void start();
    void UpdateResult();
};

myObj::myObj(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(UpdateResult()), mainClass, SLOT(on_UpdateResult()));
    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(start()), this, SLOT(startFunction()));

    percent++;
    percentTimer = new QTimer();
    percentTimer->moveToThread(&workerThread);
    percentTimer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(percentTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this,SLOT(percentUpdate()));

}

myObj::~myObj() {
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
    if (percentTimer) percentTimer->deleteLater();
}

void myObj::doWork()
{
    emit start();
    workerThread.exec();    
}

void myObj::startFunction()
{
    percentTimer->start();
    QThread::sleep(60);
    percentTimer->stop();    
}

void myObj::percentUpdate()
{
    qDebug() << "In Timer" << percent++;
    emit UpdateResult();

}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through this in a debugger? Start by putting a breakpoints in each method. Which ones get called, and in what order?

Comment: everything works fine, except slot percentUpdate never get called on timeout @MrEricSir

Comment: @MrEricSir, try to move `connect(percentTimer ...)` before `percentTimer->moveToThread(...);`

Comment: same results @RealFresh , 
connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), percentTimer,SLOT(start())) works fine but that wont work in my application, because i have to start, stop, and change interval at some intervals

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are trying to start your QTimer from a different thread than the one that created it. When using QTimer and threads, you should be very careful to create your QTimer in the thread that will control it.

From [QTimer class documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details):

> In multithreaded applications, you can use QTimer in any thread that has an event loop. To start an event loop from a non-GUI thread, use QThread::exec(). Qt uses the timer's thread affinity to determine which thread will emit the timeout() signal. Because of this, **you must start and stop the timer in its thread**; it is not possible to start a timer from another thread.

In your case `percentTimer = new QTimer();` is executed from the main thread, (even though you used `moveToThread` before, this is still the main thread executing it), while your `doWork` and `start` signals are emitted from `workerThread`.

You can for instance do your `new QTimer` from a `void init()` slot called from your `workerThread`, rather than in the constructor, to ensure that the `QTimer` is created and owned by the proper thread.

```
myObj::myObj(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), percentTimer(nullptr)
{
    moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(UpdateResult()), mainClass, SLOT(on_UpdateResult()));
    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(init()));
    connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(start()), this, SLOT(startFunction()));

    percent++;
}

void myObj::init() {
    percentTimer = new QTimer();
    percentTimer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(percentTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(percentUpdate()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should shart `workerThread` to let `myObj` work in its context (start it **after** creating required connections because slots connected to `start` signal possibly would not be executed otherwise). 
Instead of using `QThread::sleepFor` you should use something like this:

```
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer::singleShot(60000, &loop, SLOT(exit()));
loop.exec();
```

to create delays, because `QThread::sleepFor` freezes overall thread execution. And so none of your events will be processed that bound to this thread.

`workerThread.exec()` is useless here.

Comment: it's `SLOT(exit(int))` or `SLOT(quit())`, but not `SLOT(exit())`